# Не распознается второй Scanner в while?

Tags: java, while, scanner

Почему прога не распознает второй `Scanner` в цикле [while](/questions/tagged/while)?

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);  
System.out.println("Ввести заметку?");  
String text = scanner.nextLine();  
System.out.println(text);  
while (!text.equals("N"))  {  
    System.out.print("Ввести дату:");  
    int day1 = scanner.nextInt();  
    now.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day1);  
    System.out.println(now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + " Август");  
    System.out.println("Добавьте Заметку:");  

    System.out.println("Ввести заметку?");    
    text=scanner.nextLine(); // ТУТ
}
```

Comment: "прога не распознает" - что это значит?

Comment: т.е не выполняет второй scanner(то что в цикле while).

Comment: если даже в цикле  while ввожу "N"  цикл while выполняется

Comment: Вы заменили `while (text!="N")  {` на `while (!text.equals("N"))  {`?

Comment: да,забыла тут исправить

Comment: @Igor это гоп-прогерский язык